# Smooth fppf covering

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $G$: Alg$_{/R}\to $Ab an abelian fppf sheaf. Let SmoothAlg$_{/R}$ be the category of smooth $R$-algebras. Is the value of $G$ determined by the value of the restriction of $G$ to SmoothAlg$_{/R}$?

It would be enough to show that any $R$-algebra has an fppf covering by smooth $R$-algebras, but I can’t seem to prove/disprove this result or find a good reference for it.

I would also appreciate any general reference about the fppf topology / fppf sheaves. I’m happy to read things in EGA/SGA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely not true.

While one can say something more generally, I think it's instructive to restrict ourselves to the assumption that:

- $R=k$, a field which, for simplicity, I will assume is perfect,
- $G$ is representable by a finite-type group $k$-scheme (also denoted $G$) -- note that the fppf topology is subcanonical (i.e., every representable presheaf is a sheaf).

If $G$ is a smooth group $k$-scheme, then the answer to your question is evidently *yes* by a Yoneda argument. If $G'$ were another smooth group $k$-scheme such that $G$ and $G'$ take the same values on $\mathrm{SmoothAlg}_k$, then there is an isomorphism of $G$ and $G'$ in the category of presheaves on $(\mathrm{SmoothAlg}_k)^\mathrm{op}$ which, as $G$ and $G'$ are actually still representable in this smaller subcategory of $(\mathrm{Alg}_k)^\mathrm{op}$, they must be isomorphic by Yoneda.

In fact, I claim that this recoverability of $G$ from its values on $\mathrm{AlgSmooth}_k$ is essentially equivalent to being smooth in some sense. Namely, if $G$ is now just any representable sheaf, then observe that any smooth $k$-algebra $S$ is reduced, and so

$$G(S)=\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Spec}(S),G)=\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Spec}(S),G_\mathrm{red})=G_\mathrm{red}(S),$$

where $G_\mathrm{red}\subseteq G$ is the reduced subscheme (which is still a group scheme -- see [Milne, Corollary 1.39]). But, observe that $G_\mathrm{red}$ is actually smooth (see [Milne, Proposition 1.26 and Proposition 1.28]).

So, combining the above observations, we can conclude the following.

> **Proposition:** Let $k$ be a perfect field, and $G$ and $G'$ be two finite-type group schemes over $k$ viewed as sheaves on $\mathrm{Alg}_k$. Then the restrictions $G|_{\mathrm{SmoothAlg}_k}$ and $G'|_{\mathrm{SmoothAlg}_k}$ are isomorphic if and only if $G_\mathrm{red}$ and $G'_\mathrm{red}$ are isomorphic.

In characteristic $0$ every such $G$ is reduced (e.g., see [Milne, Theorem 3.23]), but there are many non-reduced groups if the characteristic of $k$ is $p>0$ (e.g., $\mu_p$).

You were correct though, that this claim would follow if every (presumably you wanted finite type) $k$-algebra had an fppf cover by smooth $k$-algebras. But, this can never happen unless the algebra is itself smooth -- the fppf topology is quite good at remembering structural properties. For instance, [Tag 033D](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/033D) is all about properties that descend along an fppf cover and they include, for instance, reduced, normal, and regular.

For places to read about the fppf topology, I am not sure what you are trying to learn about. Are you trying to learn about the formalism of sheaves on a site, or about what properties hold for the fppf site? If it's the former then I think any good book on the topic will do (e.g., I like Milne's **published** book on etale cohomology -- not his online notes). If it's the latter, I don't know if there is a really a good reference, as it's a bit of technical topic. In fact, the Stacks Project might be one of your best bets.

**References:**

[Milne] Milne, J.S., 2017. Algebraic groups: the theory of group schemes of finite type over a field (Vol. 170). Cambridge University Press.